# HTTP Basic Authentication cURL using PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to pull in data from an API using HTTP Basic authentication. The HTTP requests to the API are protected with HTTP Basic authentication. HTTP Basic authentication consists of a token and secret.

I have tried many different techniques, but keep getting the response that authentication was not provided.  I am not sure if the token:secret method is different from username:password but I cannot get this to authenticate.

stdClass Object
(
    [error_message] => Authentication not provided.
)

Here is the API documentation  - https://www.whatconverts.com/api/

```
<?php


$token = "xxx";
$secret = "yyy";
$response = get_web_page("https://leads.seekmomentum.com/api/v1/leads");
$resArr = array();
$resArr = json_decode($response);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($resArr); echo "</pre>";

function get_web_page($url) {
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "test", // name of client
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => "CURLAUTH_BASIC",  // authentication method
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => "$token:$secret",  // authentication

    ); 


    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $content  = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried separate CURLOPT_USERNAME and CURLOPT_PASSWORD?

Comment: Thanks for your credentials... might want to go get those changed/invalidated immediately.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `CURLAUTH_BASIC` - it's a constant, not a value.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => "CURLAUTH_BASIC",  // authentication method
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's a string, not a curl constant. Try

```
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_BASIC,  // authentication method
```

instead.

it's the difference between:

```
define('FOO', 'bar');

echo FOO // outputs bar
echo "FOO" // outputs FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your global variables into the local scope. To do this...

Change:

```
function get_web_page($url) {
```

To:

```
function get_web_page( $url, $token, $secret ) {
```

and change:

```
$response = get_web_page("https://leads.seekmomentum.com/api/v1/leads");
```

To:

```
$response = get_web_page( "https://leads.seekmomentum.com/api/v1/leads", $token, $secret );
```

and:

Remove the quotes around CURLAUTH_BASIC - it's a constant, not a value. (hat tip to @iainn)

Comment: Thanks Ben! That did it.

Comment: @user2748363 Glad I could help. Please select my answer as the answer to the question.